# Laravel Gate redirect on deny

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm using Gate to check if a user has a certain ability. In my case it's a pretty basic set up where I check if a user can access a certain module.

In the boot method in de AuthServiceProvider I added the following

```
$user = auth()->user();

$gate->define('manage-user-groups', function($user) {
    return $user->isAdmin();
});

$gate->define('manage-users', function($user) {
    return $user->isAdmin();
});

// more code..
```

Then in my UserController I have this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    if(Gate::denies('manage-users')) {
        return redirect('unauthorized');
        // somehow this seems te get ignored because the unaccessible view gets displayed anyway.
    }
}
```

But I'm never getting redirected to my unauthorized page. It gets in the denies section because I can dump and die stuff there. The `abort` function does work but not the redirect?

How can I redirect a user to a page if he enters an invalid route for his access level?

Comment: what message you got for redirect this route?

Comment: None, it just displays e.g. the index, show or edit route instead of redirecting to the unauthorized page.

Comment: if you are using gate you should use it on specific method,cause gate are for specific part not for full controller,if need for full controller middleware is better to use.

Comment: I'll have a look at that. I figured the __construct() method would be a good place to put it ;)

Comment: Works like a charm indeed. I've put some checking stuff in a private method and supplied each method with the check to redirect or not.